# Display only a part of the name if characters exceed a limit in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to display a message once the user logs in.

In the case where number of characters exceed 8, how can I display only the first 8 characters of a name followed by ".." ? (Eg: Monalisa..)

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        username: 'AVERYLONGGGNAMMEEE'
    }
});
```

Here is my [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/t2wm7qbh/)

Comment: Take a look https://jsfiddle.net/t2wm7qbh/1/

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Here is my answer fiddle : [ANSWER-DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/t2wm7qbh/3/)

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="username.length<8">Welcome, {{ username }}</div>
  <div v-else>Welcome, {{ username.substring(0,8)+".." }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! More accurate in one line:

 {{ username.length < 50 ? username : username.substring(0,50) + "..."}}

Comment: I think its better to put the "logic" to computed instead of having it in the template.

Comment: it works only if username already is at the beginning. But if username has gotten by some late query, it will be error "substring.. of null"

Answer (score 24):

**UPDATE VUE 3**

Filters have been removed from Vue 3.

With Vue3, you must use `globalProperties` if you want to be able to use a function in several components.

```
app.config.globalProperties.$filters = {
  str_limit(value, size) {
    if (!value) return '';
    value = value.toString();

    if (value.length <= size) {
      return value;
    }
    return value.substr(0, size) + '...';
  }
}
```

Use it like that:

```
{{ $filters.str_limit(8) }}
```

**FOR VUE 2**

You can also register a [filter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html).

You can reuse the function simply in your project.

```
Vue.filter('str_limit', function (value, size) {
  if (!value) return '';
  value = value.toString();

  if (value.length <= size) {
    return value;
  }
  return value.substr(0, size) + '...';
});
```

Use it like that :

```
<div id="app">
  <div>Welcome, {{ username | str_limit(8) }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should be the validate answer!

Comment: Filters are removed from Vue 3.0 and no longer supported.
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/filters.html

Comment: Aw man, why did they remove those. Its a super useful idea.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this by using computed properties.

```
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
  username: 'AVERYLONGGGNAMMEEE'
 },

 computed: {
   strippedUsername: function(){
      if(this.username.length > 5) {
         return this.username.slice(0,4);
      }
      return this.username;
   }
}


});
```

Answer (score 7):

you want a computed property that check if the string is > 8 chars and make modifications and use that computed property in your template.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    username: 'AVERYLONGGGNAMMEEE'
  },
  computed: {
    usernameLimited(){
      if ( this.username.length > 8 ) {
        return this.username.substring(0,8) + '...'
      } else {
        return this.username
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can do this with css, you should.

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: This will not work if we want text on multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use [substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) method to get part of the name:

```
var namePart = this.username.substr(0, 8) + '..';
```

Or you can use CSS `overflow: hidden;` and `text-overflow: ellipsis;` properties: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gxsbzohk/1/).

Answer (score 0):

## Provide / Inject (Vue3)

In this solution I used the *str_limit* function presented  above, but I decided to "serve" it to my component using [Provide / Inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html) API.

The main idea is to have a separate file where all my injectable helper functions can be defined.

I started by creating a "providers" folder at the same level as my **main.js** and placing the following index.js inside of it. The idea was to have a dedicated place to define all my helper functions.

**providers/index.js**

```
const providers={
    strLimit: (value, size) => {
      
        if (!value) return '';
        value = value.toString();

        if (value.length <= size) {
            return value;
        }
        return value.substr(0, size) + '...';
    }
}

export default providers;
```

In this simplified **App.vue**, I import the provide method defined in **providers/index.js** into the app:

**App.vue**

```
 import providers from "./providers";

    export default {
      name:"App",
      data(){
        return {
        }
      },
      provide:providers
    }
```

In my main.js I create the vue app, pass the **App.vue** shown above and mount it:

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from "./App";

const app = createApp(App)
 app.mount('#app');
    app.config.errorHandler = (err) => {
       console.log(err);
    }
```

Now inside my component I inject the strLimit method:

**component.vue**

```
<template>
<h1>{{clip(title,20)}}</h1>

</template>
<script>

export default {
  name: "myComponent",
  inject:['strLimit'],
  data(){
    return {
      title:"This is a very long title, which should be clipped at around 20 characters"
    }
  },
  methods:{
    clip(text, length){
      return this.strLimit(text, length);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it selecting part of the string below that limit and then adding an *ellipse* to the end. Notice that `username` has to exist as a string for this to work.

```
<div id="app">
    <div>
        Welcome, {{ username.length >= 8 ? username.substring(0,8) + ".." : username }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter like this in template:

```
{{ row.item.description | strLimit(limitForDescription) }}
```

define limit number

```
data() {
    return {
        limitForDescription: 7,
```

define filter

```
filters: {
    strLimit: function (str, limit) {
        if (!str) return '';
        str = str.toString();

        if (str.length <= limit) {
            return str;
        }
        return str.substr(0, limit) + '...';
    }
},
```

Hope it helps, :)

Answer (score -1):

Think this way it can take care of one line. And checking for null values to avoid **'[Vue warn]: Error in render: “TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null” with .substring()'**

```
{{ username && username.length < 8 ? username : username.substring(0,8)+".."  }}
```