# Vuetify v-btn text behaviour

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have the following set of buttons:

```
<template>
    <v-card
        color="secondary"
        elevation="6"
    >
        <v-card-title>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            Three buttons
        </v-card-title>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
        <v-card-text>
            <v-row>
                <v-col cols="12" sm="4" v-for="button in buttons" :key="button.id">
                    <v-btn color="primary" x-large block>
                        <span style="word-break: normal !important;">{{button.text}}</span>
                    </v-btn>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
        </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            //This is not a production code. The button texts are obtained via api and their length is variable
            buttons: [
                {id:1, text: "I'm a button"},
                {id:2, text: "I'm another button. Bla, bla, bla, bla"},
                {id:3, text: "I'm a button too"}
            ]
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

In this example texts are hard-coded but really I'm getting that texts from an API. Its length is variable and I can't know it beforehand. I need:

1. The text never overflows the space of the button as it is happening in the button 2.
2. Let the button text use the lines it needs. 1,2,10 ... depending on the length of it.
   Always growing vertically and with a line break as would grant the css property 'word-break: normal;'
3. The width of the button remains fixed occupying the entire width of the column, as the 'block' property should cause.

All this must be fulfilled in desktop, tablet and mobile views.

You can test it [here](https://codepen.io/jssDev-/pen/bGoMeBx).

Comment: Maybe this could be the solutions from post 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639068/display-only-a-part-of-the-name-if-characters-exceed-a-limit-in-vue-js

Comment: No, I don't want to show only part of the text. I want to show all the text, occupying the lines that it needs for it

Comment: Well you could have a function which knows the width and use it as variable to know where you should break the line for text.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a clean solution to me. I would rather use built-in features from the Vuetify library or maybe CSS, just like the word-break property works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
.v-btn__content {
  white-space: normal;
  flex: auto;
}
```

and:

```
.v-btn {
  min-height: 52px;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It comes close but it is not the solution. With 4 lines the text keeps overflowing. Take a look: https://codepen.io/jssDev-/pen/bGoMeBx

Comment: @jssDev hey mate, check now pls, I updated my answer :)

Comment: Perfect Nikola, thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome mate, cheers :)